# Uploaded image URL not being stored in firestore the first time I setDoc

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, file-upload, firebase-storage

I am trying to store the downloadLink from firebase's storage into firestore. I am able to set all the data, and I am able to set the link, the second time I click the "post" button.

I know the issue has to do with asynchronous functions, but I'm not experienced enough to know how to solve the issue.

In the "createPost" function, I am console logging "i am the URL: {url}" and in the "uploadFile" function, I am console logging "look at me {url}" to debug.

I noticed the "I am the URL" outputs nothing and then shortly after, the "look at me" outputs the URL.

setDoc() of course stores the imageLink as an empty string.

What can I do to solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated or any documentation to help with my understanding of async functions.

Here is my code:
const PostModal = (props) => {

```
const makeid = (length) => {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

const [descriptionText, setDescriptionText] = useState("");
const [addressText, setAddressText] = useState("");
const [venueText, setVenueText] = useState("");
const [startTimeText, setStartTimeText] = useState("");
const [endTimeText, setEndTimeText] = useState("");
const [shareImage, setShareImage] = useState("");
const [videoLink, setVideoLink] = useState("");
const [assetArea, setAssetArea] = useState(""); 
const [url, setURL] = useState("");
const { data } = useSession();

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${makeid(5) + shareImage.name}`);

const uploadFile = () => {
    if (shareImage == null) return;
    uploadBytes(storageRef, shareImage).then( (snapshot) => {
        //console.log("Image uploaded")
        getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then( (URL) => 
            {
                setURL(URL);
                console.log(`look at me: ${URL}`)});
    });
}

const createPost = async () => {
    var idLength = makeid(25);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadFile()
    console.log(`I am the URL: ${url} `)

    setDoc(doc(db, "posts", idLength), {
                eventDescription: descriptionText,
                eventAddress: addressText,
                venueName: venueText,
                startTime: startTimeText,
                endTime: endTimeText,
                imageLink: url,
                videoLink: videoLink,
                username: data.user.name,
               companyName: !data.user.company ? "" : data.user.company,
                timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
            });
}

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const image = e.target.files[0];
    if(image === '' || image === undefined) {
        alert('not an image, the file is a ${typeof image}');
        return;
    }
    setShareImage(image);
};

const switchAssetArea = (area) => {
    setShareImage("");
    setVideoLink("");
    setAssetArea(area);
};

const reset = (e) => {
    setDescriptionText("");
    setAddressText("");
    setVenueText("");
    setStartTimeText("");
    setEndTimeText("");
    setShareImage("");
    setVideoLink("");
    setURL("");
    props.handleClick(e);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This was taken from a reddit user who solved my answer. Big thank you to him for taking the time to write out a thoughtful response.

So, you're kinda right that your issue has a bit to do with asynchronicity, but it's actually got nothing to do with your functions being async, and everything to do with how useState works.

Suffice it to say, when you call uploadFile in the middle of your createPost function, on the next line the value of url has not yet changed. This would still be true even if uploadFile were synchronous, because when you call a useState setter function, in this case setURL, the getter value url doesn't change until the next time the component renders.
This actually makes perfect sense if you stop thinking about it as a React component for a moment, and imagine that this was just vanilla JavaScript:

```
someFunction () {
  const url = 'https://www.website.com';
  console.log(url);
  anotherFunction();
  yetAnotherFunction();
  evenMoreFunction();
  console.log(url);
}
```

In this example, would you ever expect the value of url to change? Probably not, since url is declared as const, which means if the code runs literally at all, it's physically impossible for the value of url to change within a single invocation of someFunction.
Functional components and hooks are the same; in a single "invocation" (render) of a functional component, url will have the same value at every point in your code, and it's not until the entire functional component re-renders that any calls to setURL would take effect.

This is an extremely common misunderstanding; you're not the first and you won't be the last. Usually, it's indicative of a design flaw in your data flow - why are you storing url in a useState to begin with? If you don't need it to persist across distinct, uncoupled events, it's probably better to treat it like a regular JavaScript value.
Since uploadBytes returns a promise, you could make uploadFile asynchronous as well, and ultimately make uploadFile return the information you need back to createPost, like this:

```
const uploadFile = async () => {
  if (shareImage == null) return;
  const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, shareImage);
  // console.log("Image uploaded")
  const URL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
  return URL;
};
```

All I've done here us un-nest your .then calls, pulling the trapped values out into the usable scope of your uploadFile function. Now, you can change that one line of createPost to this:

```
const url = await uploadFile();
```

and eliminate your useState altogether.